# $f_n = |x|^{1 + 1/n}$ differentiable, $(f_n')_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges pointwise?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Let $f_n = |x|^{1+1/n}$. Show that $(f_n')_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges point wise to:

$$g(x)=\begin{cases} -1 & \text{if }x < 0\\
           0 & \text{if }x=0\\
           1 & \text{if }x > 0 \end{cases}$$

I know that $f_n'(x) = (1+1/n)|x|^{1/n}\frac{|x|}{x}$, so I'd have to find an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n > N$, then $|(1+1/n)|x|^{1/n}\frac{|x|}{x} + 1| < \epsilon$ if $x < 0$, $|(1+1/n)|x|^{1/n}\frac{|x|}{x}| < \epsilon$ if $x = 0$, and $|(1+1/n)|x|^{1/n}\frac{|x|}{x} - 1| < \epsilon$ if x > 0. The pointwise convergence is obvious to me if I were just to take the limit of $f_n'$ as $n \to \infty$, but I'm not sure how to solve it using the epsilon definition.

Answer (score 1):

- If $x<0$, then $f'_n(x)=-1-1/n$. So for all $\epsilon>0$, take $N=\max(1,[1/\epsilon]+1)$. Then for $n>N$, 
  $$|f'_n(x)-(-1)|=1/n<1/N\leq \epsilon.$$
- If $x=0$, $f'_n(x)=0$ by using limit argument (your derivation formula will fail at this case).
- If $x>0$, then $f'_n(x)=1+1/n$. I think you can finish the rest.